# Redirect To Specific Controller/Action method From Action Filter Attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, redirect, filter

I have made a Filter which chacks the session variable is null or not.
If it has no value then I redirect to Login page.
The code for this filter if like-

```
public class AuthorizerActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute , IActionFilter
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserInfo"] == null)
                {
                   filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                            new RouteValueDictionary {{ "Controller", "UserLogin" },
                                                      { "Action", "UserLogin" } });
                }
            }
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

And I register this filter into Global.asax like that-

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new AuthorizerActionFilter());
```

Every request in my application firstly goes to this Filter.
When I run my application first time this filter run twice and open Login page, it did not redirect from filter since it is not a ajax request.
I fill the Login credential and when I click to Login, a ajax request firstly goes to this filter.
Here is my problem, this time nothing happen. I mean when I debug the AuthorizerActionFilter filter code, this filter run again and again. Why it is happening Is there any problem in Redirecting the Controller-Action?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you are going to get an infinite number of request processing. When your ajax call is made, your filter will return the response with the new location  `UserLogin\UserLogin` ( and it is an ajax call). If you put a breakpoint in your filter you can see that it is going to be hit infinite times!

You should update your client & server side code to do a non ajax redirect to UserLogin.

First of all, for ajax request, you should consider sending a json response.

```
 public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
 {
    if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserInfo"] == null)
            {

              var url = new UrlHelper(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext
                                      .RequestContext).Action("UserLogin", "UserLogin");
              filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
              filterContext.Result = new JsonResult { Data = new { LoginUrl = url };
            }
         }
     }
     base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

And in your javascript, have a global `ajaxComplete` where you check the status property value and if it is 401(which we set in our action filter), redirect o the LoginUrl property value.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (a, xhr, c) {
   if (xhr.status === 401) {
         var d = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
         window.location.href = d.LoginUrl;
   }
});
```

Comment: When there is an ajax call only then i have to check about the Session have some value. If it has no value then I have to redirect to the UserLogin controller and UserLogin action.

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer which handles the ajax request scenario

Comment: Is it not possible to Redirect any Controller/Action from filter directly??

Comment: @DivyamSrivastava - think about how it works.  If your ajax call is redirected, it will then process a new ajax call, which will also get redirected.  The only way out of this loop is to intercept it and do a full page (non-ajax) redirect on the client side.  How else do you think this would happen?  The page won't redirect based on a ajax redirect.  They're two different contexts

Answer (score 0):

above is giving error "   This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet."